# DB when upgrade openfire

Tags: chat, openfire

i have a openfire server version 3.9.3 with Monitoring plugin version 1.4.4. I want to upgrade to newest version(openfire 4.1.6 and monitor plugin 1.5.7). Can i use current database for new version(openfire and plugin)?. does it lost any data?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a newer version of Openfire starts, it will automatically update the database. Your data will be safe. You should, of course, create backups, just in case.